# Excel multiple row to multiple column transformation

Tags: excel, ms-access, row, transform, multiple-columns

I have a spreadsheet with over 6500 rows displaying a list of chemicals and their relationships in the following format:

```
Chemical | 1,1,2-Trichloro-1,2,2-trifluoroethane :- {FREON TC} | FREON TC  
Chemical | 1,1,2-Trichloro-1,2,2-trifluoroethane :- {FREON TC} | ug/l    
Chemical | 1,1,2-Trichloro-1,2,2-trifluoroethane :- {FREON TC} | mg/l
```

I want to transform this all into one row e.g.

```
Chemical | 1,1,2-Trichloro-1,2,2-trifluoroethane :- {FREON TC} | FREON TC | ug/l | mg/l
```

This is just an extract of this spreadsheet and there are many chemicals. Any advice much appreciated. This is an exported spreadsheet from an Access database so if there is an Access query that can help I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Have found an answer using power query in Excel, required only some minor changes (delimiter character) but worked perfectly:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/power-bi/1063813-convert-2nd-column-values-rows-when-column-1-same-name.html